# Google Analytics case sensitive - how to use Filters

Tags: google-analytics

GA shows different views like /teacher/, /Teacher/, /TEACHER/ for the one data.
When I need to gather data for /teacher/, then I would have to collect data from  /teacher/, /Teacher/, /TEACHER/.
I tried to use Filters but then there is no way to save the setting.
I did:
Filters > Custom > Lowercase > Filter Field: Campaign Target URL
BUT there is no Save button. There is only Back button.

Appreciate any helps.

Comment: I've suggested this should probably be moved to superuser discussion about google analytics, however I think if you move  it over there you will probably also need to add more details, with maybe images of what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Edit permission at the Account level to create a new filter or modify an existing one.